# cast() only takes first id and ignores other ids in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the **[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2LNHN7QdSMDgKLgupEFxoq/13)** for better understand what is the issue.

The following sql query prints only the ones with the mp3 value of the `uploaded_file_ext` in the i_user_uploads table. As can be understood from the query, the data in `i_user_uploads` is taken from the `post_file` ids in the `i_posts` table.

I need to make a few clarifications for better understanding.
post_file actually consists of the `upload_ids` in the `i_user_uploads` table. For example, `post_file 2,14` actually represents the `upload_id` in `i_user_uploads`. It will be easier to understand if you look at the chart in the **[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2LNHN7QdSMDgKLgupEFxoq/13)**.

The output in the query should be like this. The upload_ids in post_file should be followed and the `uploaded_file_ext = 'mp3'`s in the `i_user_uploads` table should be printed on the screen.

To explain in more detail, `post_file 1` is actually `upload_id 1` in the `i_user_uploads` table. If the `uploaded_file_ext` in this `id` is `mp3`, this is printed on the screen.

The problem is that the `post_file` in the i_posts table sometimes contains more than one `id` and these `ids` are separated by commas. For example `post_file 15,2,3` or `post_file 15,2`. But `cast(P.post_file as signed int) = A.upload_id` takes only the first `id` and ignores the other `ids` after the comma.

If `15` in `post_file 15,2,3` is not an `mp3` file, and `2` is an `mp3` extension, it ignores `2` and does not print to the screen.

```
SELECT P.*,U.*,A.*
  FROM i_friends F FORCE INDEX(ixFriend)
    INNER JOIN i_posts P FORCE INDEX (ixForcePostOwner)
    ON P.post_owner_id = F.fr_two 
    INNER JOIN i_users U FORCE INDEX (ixForceUser)
    ON P.post_owner_id = U.iuid AND U.uStatus IN('1','3') AND F.fr_status IN('me', 'flwr', 'subscriber')  
    INNER JOIN i_user_uploads A FORCE INDEX (iuPostOwner)
    ON P.post_owner_id = A.iuid_fk 
    AND P.post_file <> '' AND A.uploaded_file_ext = 'mp3' 
    WHERE P.post_owner_id='1' 
       AND cast(P.post_file as signed int) = A.upload_id
    ORDER BY P.post_id
    DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: What is your expected output for this  sample data?

Comment: @forpas Please see the ids I marked in red in this screenshot. https://ibb.co/XS1M4g4 . `15,2` is the upload_id. Note that `upload_id 15` is a png file but `upload_id 2` is an `mp3` . Query should check `2`, but query checking only `15` and not checking  `2`. The query should check all ids 
https://ibb.co/ZM40sN1

Comment: You should read my answer to [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `CAST()` you can use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to check if a certain value exists inside a comma separated string:

```
WHERE P.post_owner_id='1' AND FIND_IN_SET(A.upload_id, P.post_file)
```

Comment: Your answer gives the result I want. But there is something wrong with this answer because if both ids are mp3 then it acts as if there is a different `post_id`. So, for example, `post_id` number `1` is `post_file 2,3` . Let the `uploaded_file_ext` in `upload_id 2` and `upload_id 3` be `mp3`. Result `post_id 1` is showing twice. Please check the [DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2LNHN7QdSMDgKLgupEFxoq/14) I have created for this bug. https://ibb.co/SX0jhNW

Comment: @AlwaysStudent my answer is about the question: "cast() only takes first id and ignores other ids in sql query". I proposed FIND_IN_SET() because it checks all the ids in the list and this works. If you need furthermore refinement for your query you are the only one who knows your requirement and since this is a new requirement you should ask a new question where you explain what you want.

Comment: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72070978/find-in-set-after-checking-the-ids-its-acting-like-its-two-different-posts) is the new question.