# FIND_IN_SET() After checking the id's it's acting like it's two different posts

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the **[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2LNHN7QdSMDgKLgupEFxoq/14)** for better understand what is the issue.

The following sql query prints only the ones with the mp3 value of the `uploaded_file_ext` in the i_user_uploads table. As can be understood from the query, the data in `i_user_uploads` is taken from the `post_file` ids in the `i_posts` table.

I need to make a few clarifications for better understanding.
post_file actually consists of the `upload_ids` in the `i_user_uploads` table. For example, `post_file 2,14` actually represents the `upload_id` in `i_user_uploads`. It will be easier to understand if you look at the chart in the **[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2LNHN7QdSMDgKLgupEFxoq/14)**.

The output in the query should be like this. The upload_ids in post_file should be followed and the `uploaded_file_ext = 'mp3'`s in the `i_user_uploads` table should be printed on the screen.

To explain in more detail, `post_file 1` is actually `upload_id 1` in the `i_user_uploads` table. If the `uploaded_file_ext` in this `id` is `mp3`, this is printed on the screen.

The problem is that if the cascaded ids contain mp3, the output behaves as if there were more than one post_id. So it repeats the same `post_id`.

Please check this **[image: ScreenShot]** and **[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2LNHN7QdSMDgKLgupEFxoq/14)** page. You will understand better.

```
SELECT P.*,U.*,A.*
  FROM i_friends F FORCE INDEX(ixFriend)
    INNER JOIN i_posts P FORCE INDEX (ixForcePostOwner)
    ON P.post_owner_id = F.fr_two 
    INNER JOIN i_users U FORCE INDEX (ixForceUser)
    ON P.post_owner_id = U.iuid AND U.uStatus IN('1','3') AND F.fr_status IN('me', 'flwr', 'subscriber')  
    INNER JOIN i_user_uploads A FORCE INDEX (iuPostOwner)
    ON P.post_owner_id = A.iuid_fk 
    AND P.post_file <> '' AND A.uploaded_file_ext = 'mp3' 
    WHERE P.post_owner_id='1' 
       AND FIND_IN_SET(A.upload_id, P.post_file)
    ORDER BY P.post_id
    DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: You get 2 rows for post_id = 6 because you join to i_user_uploads and this returns 2 different rows from that  table. What would be your expected result?

Comment: That's how join works.  Your posts have multiple uploads each, so a row is created for each combination of post and upload

Comment: @forpas As I mentioned in the expected result screenshot, post 6 should only be shown once.

Comment: if post 6 is only shown once, then you only get one of the MP3s from that post. Do you want to have both MP3s listed?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Yes, I want mp3s to be listed on `post_id 6`. Because there are 2 items in the `post_file 14,7` of `post_id 6`. And these items only belong to `post_id 6` .

Comment: Yes you mentioned that you want post_id=6 only once but post_id is not the only column in the results. There are 13 columns and they are not all the same in the 2 rows. Which row should be included in the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll need to do is `GROUP BY post_id` if you want one row per post id.

However, since Post #6 has multiple MP3 uploads on it, you have a businesses decision to make. Which MP3 do you want? Or do you want them all in a list somehow?

You make that decision then use a grouping function like GROUP_CONCAT, or FIRST

So to get all of the MP3s listed, GROUP_CONCAT is most likely what you want:

```
SELECT P.*,U.*,GROUP_CONCAT(A.uploaded_file_path)
  FROM i_friends F FORCE INDEX(ixFriend)
    INNER JOIN i_posts P FORCE INDEX (ixForcePostOwner)
    ON P.post_owner_id = F.fr_two 
    INNER JOIN i_users U FORCE INDEX (ixForceUser)
    ON P.post_owner_id = U.iuid AND U.uStatus IN('1','3') AND F.fr_status IN('me', 'flwr', 'subscriber')  
    INNER JOIN i_user_uploads A FORCE INDEX (iuPostOwner)
    ON P.post_owner_id = A.iuid_fk 
    AND P.post_file <> '' AND A.uploaded_file_ext = 'mp3' 
    WHERE P.post_owner_id='1' 
       AND FIND_IN_SET(A.upload_id, P.post_file)
    GROUP BY P.post_id
    ORDER BY P.post_id
    DESC LIMIT 5
```